# In language of FoL with functions and predicates removed, is there a formula which can only be satisfied by structures with infinitely many elements?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

FoL stands for first order logic.
Practically, the language only has quantifiers, equality, and logical connectives. No functions or predicates (except =).

Furthermore, I came up with a set of formulas $S=\{\exists x_1...\exists x_n[x_1\neq x_2 \cap x_1\neq x_3 \cap x_1\neq x_4 ... \cap x_{n-1}\neq x_n] : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I think this set can only be satisfied by structures with infinitely many elements. Am I right?

Then can we achieve a single formula that is only satisfied by structures with infinitely many elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, your $S$ is true exactly in the infinite sets.  You can actually then use this together with compactness to prove that there is no single sentence that is true exactly in the infinite sets.

I encourage you to try proving this on your own; the details are hidden below.

> Suppose $\varphi$ is such a sentence.  Then $\varphi$ is true in every model of $S$.  By compactness, this means $\varphi$ is actually implied by just finitely many of the sentences from $S$.  But any finitely subset of $S$ has a finite model, so this is a contradiction.
>
>
>   Incidentally, the conclusion does not change if you ask only for $\varphi$ to be true in *some* infinite set, and false in all finite sets.  This is because all infinite sets are elementarily equivalent, i.e. they all satisfy the same sentences.  This follows from Löwenheim-Skolem: if you let $T$ be the complete theory of a countable set, then $T$ has models of all infinite cardinalities, and thus is the theory of every infinite set.